# Is there a way to Web Scrape a Dynamic page with Javascript

Tags: javascript, web-scraping

so I have been having difficulties web scraping a webpage with Javascript. The webpage I am scraping loads in data dynamically with Javascript within 1 second, but when I am using Cheerio and Request it only grabs the source code.

I was wondering if there was a way to scrape the website using JS, or if I need to default to using Python?

P.S.

I have tried Nightmare.js, but that didn't seem to be working for what I want to do.
I have "rejectUnauthorized" to false since the page wouldn't load if that wasn't there, and the site is trusted.

Code:

```
var request = require("request");
var cheerio = require("cheerio");

var options = { uri: 'XXXXX',
                "rejectUnauthorized": false,
                json: true};

request(options, function(err, response, body){
    if(err){
        console.log(err);
    }
    if(!err && response.statusCode == 200){
        var $ = cheerio.load(body);
        console.log(response);
        var nameArr = [];
        $('a.href','.bgLightGreen.highlight.centered.nowrap').each(function(){
            ...
            ...
        })
   }
});
```

Comment: What you want is a headless browser; something like phantomjs or headless chrome

Comment: Checkout Nightmare.js and it's evaluate() function.